# Massive .dmg file in /Users/username/firmware/ folder: any ideas what the heck it is?

Tags: folders, dmg, firmware

So, I've discovered that there's a 2.57GB .dmg file in the /Users/username/firmware folder on my Mac (High Sierra v. 10.13.6). The filename is <058-97232-130.dmg>. There are a couple of other dmg files there too, closer to 80MB in size.

I was thinking that it's some kind of firmware update for my phone, except it's a .dmg file, not an ipsw. I've googled the filename and the folder location, and found nothing at all. Any ideas?

EDIT: Oh, one more weird thing: the file's creation/last modified date is "January/9/07" (which is the same date for the other .dmg files in the folder). But I got my computer in 2013, so I'm not sure what that tells us.

Comment: It's not an Apple firmware update - across all OS's, Apple saves firmware updates to `/Applications/Utilities/`. In fact, that folder doesn't even exist by default - it's some third party firmware update package.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site a useful resource! It may be worth investigating the hardware you have as it's most likely related to firmware updates for some 3rd party hardware (e.g. a router, printer, etc). Keep in mind that it doesn't necessarily have to be hardware that's connected to your Mac - it could be that you've just used your Mac to download the file(s) that you've subsequently used to update the firmware (e.g. a PVR, car audio/navigation, etc).

Comment: Hmm, okay. I should have mentioned, but I see other files/folders that suggest it's something to do with iPhone, like "kernelcache.release.iphone7." 

I now suspect that it's linked to the software iMyFone iOS System Recovery, which—because of where I live—was what I ended up resorting to using when my iPhone got screwed up during an iOS update. I'll check with the software creator about whether I can delete the file (i.e. whether it'll automatically download once more if/when I need it again).

Thanks!

Comment: Turn that into a answer so we can close this question and you might get some points.

Comment: Planning on doing it, once I get confirmation that this is actually the case from the software's creator. If I don't hear back, I'll turn my above into an Answer (with caveats). 

Thanks for the advice and also the warm welcome, folks!

Answer (score 1):

This folder `~/Firmware Files` is from the software `iMyFone Fixppo` e.g. for rescuing iPhone backups or iPhone permanently booting.

The `DMG` files are firmware images from iOS devices.

You probably are done with rescuing so it is safe to remove the folder.